# Reading double from binary files

Tags: c++, file, binary, double

Need's formatting, editing will take some time.

Comment: Better use `sizeof(double)` than the constant 8.

Comment: Are you sure test.txt is in binary?

Comment: you say per line but open the file in binary mode, sounds like this is the problem. is the file content created with a text editor or have you written binary double values in it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading using `fin >> d` and using `fin.read` does different things. As `fin >> d` works it seems you have a file where the string representation of a double is written. Using `fin.read` suggests that your file is written in binary which it seems it is not. Also you should better use `sizeof(double)` instead of the hard coded constant `8`.

Comment: file was written using write function.

Comment: @user2806369 when you open the file(for instance in a text editor) are you able to read its contents?

Comment: when using >> operator it is notepad readible(terrible english).

Comment: @user2806369 I mean is the file that you try to read using `>>` or `read` readable. Can you read the double value you have stored in it?

Comment: @user2806369 if the file was written in binary, then opening it in notepad++ would not help as its contents would not be human readable. Thus my theory that the file is not written in binary seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you missunderstood  the semantic of `std::ifstream::read` function. According to C++ reference:

**Note: This doc is for std::istream but applies to ifstream**

[std::istream::operator>>()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/)

**This operator (>>) applied to an input stream is known as extraction operator. It is overloaded as a member function for:**

`arithmetic types`

> Extracts and parses characters sequentially from the stream **to interpret them as the representation of a value of the proper type, which is stored as the value of val**.
>       Internally, the function accesses the input sequence by first constructing a sentry object (with noskipws set to false). Then (if good), it calls num_get::get (using the stream's selected locale) to perform both the extraction and the parsing operations, adjusting the stream's internal state flags accordingly. Finally, it destroys the sentry object before returning.

`stream buffers` and `manipulators`.

while for [std::istream::read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/):

> This function **simply copies a block of data, without checking its contents** nor appending a null character at the end.

So, when you do:

```
double d;
...
fin >> d;
```

You're storing a `double` into a double var. But ...

if you do:

```
double d;
...
fin.read((char*)&d, ...);
```

you are telling to c++: Ok here (&d) I have an address, I want you trate it as it was `char*` (the cast). And the function do what you want to do. But as you see in doc, the function will put in `&d` a **block of data** that has nothing to do with the walue you're expecting.

That's why `operator>>` works while `read` doesn't.